# Hide graphically some items iterating with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing a web-application using Angular Js.
I want to fill a div, into my html view, using the ng-repeat directive. The array used by ng-repeat has some duplicates, but in my view I want to display item only once (if an element has already been shown, its copies must be graphically hidden). How can I do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedProcedures track by $index">
    <span>{{item.id}}</span>                                            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a unique filter like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedProcedures track by $index | unique : 'id'">
    <span>{{item.id}}</span>                                            
</div>
```

Then create the unique filter:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(collection, property) {
        var output = [];
        angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            //check if it exists in output on the basis of property, if not then add to output
            output.push(item);
        }) 
        return output;
    }
})
```

'property' in the function is 'id' in the example whereas collection refers to the entire array.

Comment: I have used your approach, but now it displays nothing.

Comment: are you getting any errors, please create a plunker so i can help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to hide generated Html, but to add a filter to delete duplicates :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedProcedures track by $index  | deleteDuplicates">
. . .
</div>

angular.module('myApp').filter('deleteDuplicates', function(){ 
    return function filterCore(source)
    {        
        var out = [];
        // . . . 
        return(out);
    };


});
```

[Here is](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) the AngularJS custom filter tutorial.